# How to use data from a Promise in <Fragment> React

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, fragment, es6-promise, dispatch

I need to get the name of the current user in my React app, so I sent the data from the action/auth.js to Navbar.js, in the Navbar I got a Promise, so I user then to get the data. and I managed to console.log the data. yet I can't use it in order to show it to the user.
Here's my auth.js function for sending the data:

```js
export const get_user_data = () => async dispatch => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('access')) {
    const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        };
         try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/me/`, config);
            let name = res.data.first_name +" "+ res.data.last_name;
            return name;


        } catch (err) {

            return err;
        }
    } else {
        return "else accesss"
    }
};
```

And this is my Navebar.js where I'm trying to show the data:

```js
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logout, get_user_data } from '../actions/auth';


const Navbar = ({ get_user_data,logout, isAuthenticated}) => {

    console.log("get_user_data", get_user_data().then(res=>{
    console.log("res", res)}));

    const get_name = () => (
    get_user_data().then(res=> {return res})
    );

    const guestLinks = () => (
        <Fragment>
            <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link className='nav-link' to='/login'>לכניסה</Link>
            </li>
            <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link className='nav-link' to='/signup'>להרשמה</Link>
            </li>
        </Fragment>
    );

    const authLinks = () => (

    <Fragment>
        <li className='nav-item'>
            <a className='nav-link' href='#!' onClick={logout}>ליציאה</a>
        </li>
        <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link className='nav-link' to='/homepage'>העסק שלי</Link>
        </li>
        {<li className='nav-item'>
            <Link className='nav-link'>ברוך הבא {get_name()}</Link>
        </li>}


    </Fragment>
    );

    return (

            <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light' lang="he" dir="rtl">
                <Link className='navbar-brand' to='/'>החשמלאי</Link>
                <button
                    className='navbar-toggler'
                    type='button'
                    data-toggle='collapse'
                    data-target='#navbarNav'
                    aria-controls='navbarNav'
                    aria-expanded='false'
                    aria-label='Toggle navigation'
                >
                    <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
                </button>
                <div className='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarNav'>
                    <ul className='navbar-nav'>
                        <li className='nav-item active'>
                            <Link className='nav-link' to='/'>עמוד הבית <span className='sr-only'>(current)</span></Link>
                        </li>

                        {isAuthenticated ? authLinks() : guestLinks()}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
    });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout, get_user_data })(Navbar);
```

I used get_name() function to parse the data fron the promise, but I still get the Promise error.

The React Error:

> react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Thank you!

Comment: get_name returns a promise in your code. Not a actual value react can render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Analysis

The behavior you're getting is because you're trying to display a `Promise`. You'd need to wait for the `Promise` to be resolved before displaying it. Here I'll use the `useState` and `useEffect` hook to achieve the behavior I am talking about.

## Solution

First, you'll need a state to hold your `userData`. From your code in the `get_user_data` function, let's assume the `data` we're talking about is the user name. The default value of this state will be an empty string.

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
```

Then, I'll create an `useEffect` hook to use your `get_user_data` function to populate the newly created `name` state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  get_user_data().then((data) => {
    setName(data);
  });
}, []);
```

This hook will get the data and set the `name` state when the fetch is finished.

Then we'll need to use this `name` state wherever we need. The behavior of this component is that it'll display `''` when we're getting the user name, but once the data is available the UI will display it. Putting it all together, we have:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logout, get_user_data } from '../actions/auth';


const Navbar = ({ get_user_data,logout, isAuthenticated}) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
      get_user_data().then((data) => {
        setName(data);
      });
    }, []);

    const guestLinks = () => (
        <Fragment>
            <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link className='nav-link' to='/login'>לכניסה</Link>
            </li>
            <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link className='nav-link' to='/signup'>להרשמה</Link>
            </li>
        </Fragment>
    );

    const authLinks = () => (

    <Fragment>
        <li className='nav-item'>
            <a className='nav-link' href='#!' onClick={logout}>ליציאה</a>
        </li>
        <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link className='nav-link' to='/homepage'>העסק שלי</Link>
        </li>
        {<li className='nav-item'>
            <Link className='nav-link'>ברוך הבא {get_name()}</Link>
        </li>}


    </Fragment>
    );

    return (

            <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light' lang="he" dir="rtl">
                <Link className='navbar-brand' to='/'>החשמלאי</Link>
                <button
                    className='navbar-toggler'
                    type='button'
                    data-toggle='collapse'
                    data-target='#navbarNav'
                    aria-controls='navbarNav'
                    aria-expanded='false'
                    aria-label='Toggle navigation'
                >
                    <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
                </button>
                <div className='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarNav'>
                    <ul className='navbar-nav'>
                        <li className='nav-item active'>
                            <Link className='nav-link' to='/'>עמוד הבית <span className='sr-only'>(current)</span></Link>
                        </li>

                        {isAuthenticated ? authLinks() : guestLinks()}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout, get_user_data })(Navbar);
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked! that seemed so obvious I just didn't know because I'm new to React.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using redux and connect to connect to your state.
If you have used hooks before this might be shorter and cleaner:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  // Instead of using connect to get state, you can use the hook useSelector:
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.auth.isAuthenticated);
  // No user to begin with
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  // This will run once when the navbar renders for the first time
  useEffect(() => {
    get_user_data().then(fetchedUser => setUser(fetchedUser))
  }, [])

  function dispatchSomeAction() {
    // Fire of action to redux
    dispatch({ type: "logout" })
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {user !== null && (<div>{user.name}</div>)}
      <div>{isAuthenticated ? <p>Authenticated!</p> : <p>Not Authenticated</p>}</div>
      <button onClick={dispatchSomeAction} >I will dispatch a action to redux</button>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Also read about redux-thunk if you are using redux. It allows you to do async stuff like API calls and store the returned values in your state :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't try this solution but I understood why it didn't work before.
Thanks.